# Splitting a string into parts

Tags: c#

I would like to split a string in C# for example:
120530

so it will be like this:
Day: 12
Time: 0530

But it will be without spaces, just as it is 120530

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean 12 days, 5 hours and 30 minutes?

Comment: Do you *always* want to split after the second character? Is `String.Substring` enough?

Comment: Will it always be 6 digits with the first 2 being day and last 4 being time?

Comment: can't you just right a simple string.SubString method..?

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that you know that it will always be 6 digits with the first 2 being day and last 4 being time.

Utilize the Substring() method of your string object...

```
string allTogether = "120530";
string day = allTogether.Substring(0, 2);
string time = allTogether.Substring(2);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var dayAndTime = "120530";
var day = dayAndTime.Substring(0, 2);
var time = dayAndTime.Substring(2, 4);
```

Comment: It gives me an error says:
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in M.A.T - Metar Decoder.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: The code is:
            var part1 = elements.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
            var part2 = elements.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
            string day = part2.Substring(0, 2);
            string time = part2.Substring(2, 4);
            string p1 = "Airport: " + part1 + "\r\n";
            string p2 = "\nDay:" + day + time;
            string p3 = "\nTime:" + time;
            metarDecode.Text = p1 + "" + p2 + "" + p3;

Comment: I can't do much with your code as long as I dont know what's inside `elements`.

Comment: That is:

            `var test = textBox1.Text;
            var elements = test.Split(new[]
            {
                ' '
            });`